# Imageflow speed up loading images

Tags: javascript, caching, imageflow

It takes about 7 seconds for 12 images to load the site. Each image has about 200 kb which than gets a reflection (then about 270kb for each file). Isn't imageflow using a cache? Do I have to add a setting? When is this cache refreshed (new images generated)?

Perhaps I should mention that the files are PNG-24 files with transparency ...

Edit:

I found out that without using reflect3.php the site is extremely fast. I wanted to use `reflectionGET:'&cache=1'` but this doesn't help.

Seems that `preloadImages: true` does the trick. The loading only takes half the time.

Comment: you have worked with imageFlow , i wanted to know how to increase gap between images , imageflow.js left property is calculated with different variable . how to increase gap

Comment: Some time has gone since I worked with it. At the moment I can't say something about it. I would recommend you post a question so that more people will see it.